# In Australia, how do I send a letter of demand to a person but don't know his physical address, only email address?

Tags: civil-law, civil-procedure, tort, litigation, demand-letter

I need to send a letter of demand to a person but I don't know his address. I only know his work address. This for a Small Claims Dispute (Less then $10K). I am in Australia.

I have his email and can get a read receipt.

Will this suffice the courts if I initiate a litigation process?

or do I still need to send the letter to his physical address?

Answer (score 1):

### You email it to them

However, if you want to take them to court, you need to issue a [Statement of Claim](https://www.lawaccess.nsw.gov.au/Pages/representing/Local_courts_small_claims/owed_money/starting_your_case/completing_soc.aspx), not a Letter of Demand. A letter of demand is not a court document and has no legal consequences other than, perhaps, being used as evidence in a subsequent action.

A Statement of Claim must be served in accordance with the [court rules](https://www.lawaccess.nsw.gov.au/Pages/representing/Local_courts_small_claims/owed_money/starting_your_case/serving_soc.aspx).  Different rules apply to serving a statement of claim: ​​on an individual, on a company, on a business, on a partnership, or outside NSW. Email service is not acceptable (without leave of the court).

Comment: Thank you I haven't looked further. But isn't a Letter of Demand a must? This person owes me money.

Comment: Nope. You can go invoice -> court if you want. Assuming it's a liquidated debt. I can screw up and throw away a letter of demand without any consequences. I can do it with a Statement of Claim too but there will be consequences.